# Maximum number of stable states of a Markov matrix

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

I wondered if the maximum number of stable states (solutions) for a sequence modeled by a Markov matrix is 1 (which means, either no stable solution or one stable solution), or it could be any number.

In other words, might there exist a Markov matrix with two or more stable states? Is there any boundary on the number of possible states?

Note: I mean by Markov matrix a matrix with all nonnegative entries and columns adding up to 1.

Comment: If the entries are not necessarily all positive, then there can be *any* number of stable states.

Comment: @Chrystomath Even if they are nonnegative? Is it possible to give me an example?

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-negative matrix gives rise to a directed graph with edges from vertices $i$ to $j$ whenever $a_{ij}>0$. Such a directed graph decomposes into a number of [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) components, and these components can be ordered from source components to intermediate components to sink components. Here is an example:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

The vertices 1 and 2 form source components, then {3,4,6,7} form an intermediate component, and 5 and 8 form sink components.

For an example with $n$ stable states, take one source vertex connected to $n$ sink vertices. Its matrix for $n=5$ is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}\tfrac{1}{6}&0&0&0&0&0\\\tfrac{1}{6}&1&0&0&0&0\\\tfrac{1}{6}&0&1&0&0&0\\\tfrac{1}{6}&0&0&1&0&0\\\tfrac{1}{6}&0&0&0&1&0\\\tfrac{1}{6}&0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ Each vector $e_2,\ldots,e_6$ is a stable state. Of course you can pick any connected directed graph: there will be as many (independent) stable states as there are sink components.